# Can I get my richtextbox to send a carriage return instead of a newline character

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a terminal emulator app that sends characters to a hardware device.  I have implemented the terminal using a richtextbox.  When the user types I read the characters from the richtextbox and send them to a hardware device via a serial port.
The hardware device expects a command string terminated with carriage return `\r`.  When I extract the text characters from my rich text box much to my chagrin when the user hits the enter key all I get is the newline character `\n`.

I can replace the newline character with a carriage return on the extracted text easily enough but I was curious is there a way to massage the richtextbox so it will send a `\r` instead of a `\n`? 
even better would be that it sends a `\r` `\n` when the user hits the enter key?

Comment: Is this the standard .NET richtextbox control and not a third party control?

Comment: Yes as far as I know i haven't added anything except what came from the Visual Studio Install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure a rich text control can display a carriage return character properly anyway. I would stick with post-processing. A simple find and replace before sending the text to your hardware device will do the trick.

Comment: Hi I'll stick with the post processing

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the user input on the Textchanged-Event...
With this you get the latest character written in the RichTextBox.
If it's a carriage return you replace it with a linefeed.

The RichTextBox is able to display both NewLine-Chars. =)

Hope it's helpful for you..